# Python Geopandas: Dissolve function does not dissolve overlapping polygons

Tags: python, geopandas, intersection, dissolve, overlay

I have developed a Python program using GeoPandas to handle overlapping polygons. The program first dissolves these overlapping polygons and then applies an overlay operation (specifically, intersection) on the target layer. Below is the function I utilized to dissolve the overlapping areas:

```
def dissolve_area(overlay_gdf, dissolve_by=None):

    dissolved = overlay_gdf.dissolve(by=dissolve_by)
    dissolved.reset_index(inplace=True)

    
    return dissolved
```

I then applied this function to my dataset, dissolving the polygons based on the 'SECTOR_ID':

```
cdf = dissolve_area(cdf,'SECTOR_ID')
```

Subsequently, I used GeoPandas to perform an overlay operation on the target layer:

```
intersection_gdf = gpd.overlay(df1=target_layer, df2=cdf, how="intersection", keep_geom_type=True)
```

However, upon inspecting the 'cdf' by converting it into a GeoPackage and visualizing it in QGIS, I observed that not all overlapping layers were dissolved as expected. For instance, consider the following scenarios:

**Picture 1:** The red layer represents the selected coverage layer where 'SECTOR_ID' = C4TKT1, and the green layer represents the target layer.

[image: Coverage Layer when SECTOR_ID = C4KT1]

**Picture 2:** The red layer represents the selected coverage layer where 'SECTOR_ID' = C4ORA2..
[image: Coverage Layer when SECTOR_ID = C4ORA2]

The target layer is intersected by four polygons from 'cdf.' It's evident that some areas of the target layer are intersected by two polygons (i.e., with 'SECTOR_ID' = C4KT1 and C4ORA2). I expected these polygons to dissolve, but it appears that they did not. Consequently, the total intersected area of the target layer exceeds its actual area because it counts the same intersected area twice.

Can you identify the mistake I may have made in my approach?

Comment: If sector id isnt the same, overlapping polygons with different ids will not dissolve, you know that right?

Comment: @BERA, I just realized that and I think that is the problem. Because overlapping polygons do not have same Sector_ID, hence they don't dissolve. I could not find any other columns from the coverage file which can be used to dissolve overlapping polygons. If I don't specify the column name, it will dissolve all polygons into one big polygon (which could be acceptable for my purpose). However, processing parcels against a single large polygon to find the intersection and within area takes a significant amount of time. Any advice?

Comment: `gdf.dissolve().explode()`